# Paypal sandbox merchant account

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am using paypal sandbox accounts to test payment through a website, one for buyer and one for receiver (personal/business). When I make a test payment from the buyer account to the merchant account the funding is adjusted for buyer but not merchant, despite the transaction showing up in notifications and in the sandbox account itself. Why could this be?

Comment: Sounds like it must be going to a different account than you think it is..??

Comment: Turns out it works if you send to friends and family but not for goods and services. It does at least work through the woo commerce checkout.